# Does anyone recognise this haiku?

Tags: consciousness

I was staying at samye ling Tibetan monastery in Scotland and writing a lot of poetry. I wrote this haiku in one go without any consideration or counting syllables, and did not feel as if I wrote it. It is much better than my usual standard:

Palms open fingers spread,
Serenity offered,
The mind now awake.

Does anyone recognise it? I am certain that I have no conscious memory of reading these words or any similar lines and am equally sure that they are not my invention! I would appreciate any insight into how they came to be. I have not subsequently experienced anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your big mind wanted to say hello.  Keep practicing and he’ll tell you even more.

Comment: Thank you for your response, my big mind and the illusory collection of achetypal traits which currently represent myself are in constant communication! The experience felt like it had more of an  independent nature. Possible hypotheses I am considering are either I had read this before ( unlikely ) or that I had been an unwitting medium.

Comment: If that’s your working theory, you’re probably barking up the wrong tree posting on a Buddhist Q&A site.  Don’t attach too much importance to the source.  It could wind up becoming an obstacle.

Comment: @Joedean7 - I see no reason think you were a medium, if there is such a thing, but I do remember recording a Schubert Impromptu once and feeling that the composer was standing next to me the whole way through, and the experience was so real it's always made me wonder.  ,

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across it. I like it. To me it doesn't have the impact we expect from Basho and his like but this is an unfair comparison.

If the last line was simply 'awake' it would work better imho, more sudden, even if the form would be compromised. To say, 'The mind now awake' is to open a can of worms, since some would say such a thing is impossible,

Comment: Thanks, it had to be 17 syllables which normally I would have been counting but in this instance I wasn't. I had only started writing haiku at the time as a response to zen koans and that one just kind of wrote itself. I was possibly reacting to a buddhist atmosphere with my subconscious perhaps more focused than usual?

Comment: And I think mind awakens now maybe?

Comment: Wrong way round! Now mind awoken?

Comment: @Joedean7 - The mind cannot awake. One could say that it is realising this that is awakening.